# Trimesh - leak memory

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, mesh

I'm using the Trimesh library to compute the curvature on each vertex of a triangulated mesh. To do, I make:

```html
 TriMesh *m = TriMesh::read(this->fichier);
m->need_curvatures();

float *degres= new float[nbr_vertices];

for(int i=0;i<nbr_vertices;i++)
 {
   degres[i]=m->curv1[i]; // get the curvature
 }

  delete [] degres;  m->clear(); delete m;
```

The problem is a leak memory detected even I clear and delete the "* m". 
The leak memory was detected by "valgrind".

this is the output of valgrind :

```html
 912 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5 of 13
==4239==    at 0x4C2CC70: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4239==    by 0x4012E54: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:296)
==4239==    by 0x5174DA0: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (allocatestack.c:589)
==4239==    by 0x599C905: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==4239==    by 0x4C67D2: trimesh::TriMesh::need_normals() (in /home/spin/spin)
==4239==    by 0x4B203D: trimesh::TriMesh::need_curvatures()
```

Any idea to  solve this issue ?

thanks.

Comment: If you used valgrind, post its output, but just the mem leak snippet

Comment: ok, i put below my first message

Comment: It might be a memory leak occurring in Trimesh. Can you compile your program with -g and with OpenMP disabled and run it again, then post the output of Valgrind?

Comment: when i delete the "-fopenmp", i have errors like "undefined reference to OMP_GET_THREAD_NUL (or to GOMP_critical_end or .. )

Answer (score 1):

`912 bytes in 3 blocks are` **possibly** `lost in loss record 5 of 13`

Possible loss might just be caching or pointer tricks and 912 bytes is hardly an issue.  Unless it's several megabytes, I would ignore it, especially if its in a library snd not in your code.

For this to be an issue, it really should be something of a much larger magnitude, and generally a behaviour that grows with longer runs.  If it were one kilobyte per call and you were doing it thousands or millions of times then it would need to be reported to the library creator

In short, no evidence of a real leak.

Run this in a loop and see if it grows significantly without settling off, otherwise you can ignore it.